# Same Form widget for two different routes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pub

Actually I had created a page that contain form widget
`addInventoryPage` with `formkey(GlobalKey<FormState>())` and there is some business requirement to use the same page with different routes
`(routes1:/inventory,routes2:/openingInventory)` with some additional params.

But when I switch from `/inventory` routes to `/openingInventory` routes I got fromKey as null

Here is the code of addInventoryPage

```
class StateCommonPage extends StatelessWidget {
  InventoryTabController _inventoryTabController = Get.find();
  VariationController _variationController = Get.find();

  CommonWidget _commonWidget = CommonWidget();
  ValidationMethods _validationMethods = ValidationMethods();
  final description = TextEditingController();
  final quantity = TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey=GlobalKey<FormState>(debugLabel: 'STATE COMMON');

  final States titleText;
  double width;
  double height;

  StateCommonPage({this.titleText});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    width = Get.width * 0.95;
    height = Get.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: height * 0.6,
          child: Form(
            key:formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Fill Details of ${titleText.toString().split('.').last.capitalizeFirst} '
                  'Process',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                ),
                ..........
```

for switching between routes `Get.offNamed('inventory');`

Here is my customDrawer

```
    class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
 Widget buildMenuListTile(BuildContext context, Menus menu) {
        return Obx(
          () => menu.menuCode == 'INVENTORY'
              ? custom.ExpansionTile(
                  initiallyExpanded: true,
                  children: buildSubMenuTile(context, menu.menuCode),
                  leading: Icon(
                    Finals.menuIconMap[menu.menuCode],
                    size: 24,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    menu.menuName,
                    style: menu.menuCode == selectedMenuId.value
                        ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4
                        : Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  ),
                )
              : ListTile(
                  selectedTileColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.3),
                  leading: Icon(
                    Finals.menuIconMap[menu.menuCode],
                    size: 24,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  selected: menu.menuCode == selectedMenuId.value,
                  hoverColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  title: Text(
                    menu.menuName,
                    style: menu.menuCode == selectedMenuId.value
                        ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4
                        : Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Get.offNamed(menu.relativePath);
                  }),
        );
      }

          }
```

Here is my Routes

```
class Routes {
 
  static const INVENTORY = '/inventory';
 
  static const OPENING_INVENTORY = '/openingInventory';

  Map<String, WidgetBuilder> test;

  static final routes = [
   
    GetPage(
      name: INVENTORY,
      page: () => InventoryBottomTabBar(),
      binding: BindingsBuilder.put(() => InventoryTabController()),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: OPENING_INVENTORY,
      page: () => InventoryBottomTabBar(),
      binding:
          BindingsBuilder.put(() => InventoryTabController()),
    )
}
```

debug Logs

> The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
> Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
>
> The following GlobalKey was specified multiple times in the widget
> tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated
> unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous
> instance is moved to the new location. The key was:
>
> - [LabeledGlobalKey#0db7f] This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its
>   previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame,
>   meaning that it either did not update at all or updated before the
>   widget was moved, in either case implying that it still thinks that it
>   should have a child with that global key. The specific parent that did
>   not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to
>   GlobalKey reparenting is:
> - ConstrainedBox(BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=484.4), renderObject: RenderConstrainedBox#37684 relayoutBoundary=up2) A
>   GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget
>   tree. When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   #0      BuildOwner.finalizeTree. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2900:15)
>   #1      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2925:8)
>   #2      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:877:19)
>   #3      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:328:5)
>   #4      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)

Comment: add code of related class to get better help

Comment: code added in question

Comment: sorry Vaishnav, not sure about the issue. looks like navigation issue.  lets add the code line which is calling this stateless widget

Comment: i  also added my customDrawer code in which I use routes and all in buildmenuListTile  used `Get.off()` methods

Comment: also added routes

Comment: please add the relevant code lines only. you are posting the complete classes. However, I am unable to reproduce the  problem

Comment: Hello I edited this please review this